# Add child view controller from .xib causes a bundle of wierd issues in ios

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add a child UIViewController whose view is in a `.xib` file.

I use following code to achieve this task.

```
  searchScopeControl = LSearchScopeControlViewController(nibName: "SearchScopeControlView", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
  self.view.addSubview(searchScopeControl!.view)
  self.addChildViewController(searchScopeControl!)

  //add constraints
  searchScopeControl?.view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
  let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchScopeControl!.view,
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width,
    relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
    toItem: self.view,
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width,
    multiplier: 1.0,
    constant: 0)
  let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchScopeControl!.view,
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
    relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
    toItem: self.topLayoutGuide,
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
    multiplier: 1,
    constant: 0)
  let left = NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchScopeControl!.view,
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
    relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
    toItem: self.view,
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
    multiplier: 1.0,
    constant: 0)
  self.view.addConstraints([width,top,left])

  searchScopeControl?.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
  println("searchScopeControl view frame \(searchScopeControl?.view.frame) bounds \(searchScopeControl?.view.bounds) constraints \(searchScopeControl?.view.constraints())")
```

The view should look like the following:
[image: This]

But when the code executes, the view's background color completely goes missing, its interaction is not available. The screenshot is attached:

[image: That]

I am not entirely sure why this happens since I properly added the view controller, its view, and their required calls. At the same time, I used proper constraints that will resize it to correct position. If remove these constraints, the entire view is simply missing.

But, even if I set these constraints the above ways, the frame of `searchScopeControl` is still unaffected, e.g `(0,0,600,80)` while it should be `(64,0,320,80)`, but its presentation on the view seems to be correct.

I am sure there are codes I am missing here, but what are they?

Comment: Do you have any constraints being set in xib file? looks like the images don't have width and height constraints and they are enlarged.

Comment: I did set constraints for all subview elements in .xib file. I think this is because my simulator's scale is larger than 100%.

Comment: What do you mean scale is larger than 1, if it is 2, do you have @2x.png images in resource bundle?

Comment: It is okay, I discovered another approach now. But speaking of the scale, I believe you can resize your simulator by going to window->scale, just in case that you do not know it yet.

Comment: Your original code missed height constraint.

Comment: I did try add height just now, but I think it has to do with how constraints are added to a view. Somehow, it causes conflict if I write out individually, or maybe I am missing more constraints, not so sure. But I have attached an answer below

Comment: Your answer does have two constraints and works, one is to make child view and superview has the same width, the other one is to make child view's height to be 72, which is missing from your original code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe the result is that simple.
I think there are some missing constraints, e.g. height. I ended up using visual format approach to solve this.
Here is the code

```swift
 let someViewControllerView = someViewController!.view
  //add constraints
  someViewControllerView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
  let viewsV = ["t":self.topLayoutGuide,"v":someViewControllerView]
  let constraintsV = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[t][v(==72)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.allZeros, metrics: nil, views: viewsV)
  let viewsH = ["v":someViewControllerView,"s":self.view]
  let constraintsH = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[v(==s)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.allZeros, metrics: nil, views: viewsH)

  self.view.addConstraints(constraintsV)
  self.view.addConstraints(constraintsH)
```

Just add this snippet after `someViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)`